# Feature to polygon tool not recognizing closed contour lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, features, contour

I am using the Feature to Polygon data management tool in ArcMap (v.10.7.1) to convert contour lines (above 1200m) to polygons. The contour lines are closed (beyond the extent of the picture which is just a crop of a small section) and I have done this successfully for other elevations with the same contour layer.

[image]

When I run the tool, the output only captures a few of the polygons. I would like to know why these contours are not recognized as being closed and what to do about this.

[image]

Comment: You have ground/figure relationship issues with the lines that dangle at the map extent. Try closing the shapes by adding the boundary box, splitting it at dangles, removing the "outside" lines, and trying again

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a little - what do you mean by 'add the boundary box' for instance? Thanks.

Comment: Also, as far as I know there are no lines that dangle at the extent - the image is just a crop of a section of the contour layer which is actually much larger and I believe has closed contour lines. Sorry if my question didn't make this clear.

Comment: Obviously the software disagrees, and the tie-breaker goes to the software.  You can locate the regions of disagreement by intersecting a coarse regular grid and looking for dangles within the cells without polygons.

Comment: Try repair geometry first to ensure all your lines are valid and then if that doesn't work being able to run feature to polygon proves you have an advanced license, run feature vertices to points https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003p000000 with the point_location of 'dangle' to find those pesky free ends quickly. There are bound to be breaks somewhere if you're not polygonizing properly, trying to find them manually would be horrible.

Comment: Repair generally only applies to polygons (ring order), though I suppose it would eliminate single vertex (degererate) lines. I've used Multipart to Singlepart to split improperly merged geometries.

Comment: @Vince for lines Repair Geometry also cleans out 0 length segments (double digitization) and empty geometries which can cause tools to fail, it will not explode multipart or resolve intersections, if that's what you want to do then have a try of Planarize Lines in the Topology Editor toolbar https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m800000012000000.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. You were right that there was a discontinuity in one of the lines which was causing this problem. Your suggestion @MichaelStimson to run Feature Vertices to Points located the spots that weren't connected, and I could then easily join them up. Thanks!